# List only Folders not files

Tags: bash

I have the following srcipt which should show me all folders in the directory, but at the moment the script list also the files under /var/www

```
 declare -a dirs
 i=1
 for d in /var/www/*
 do
         dirs[i++]="${d%/}"
 done

 for((i=1;i<=${#dirs[@]};i++))
 do
         echo $i "${dirs[i]}"
 done
```

What shoult i change to list only folders in the array?

Comment: What about just `find /var/www -type d`?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
printf "%s\n" /var/www/*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You could perform a check whether it's a directory.  Say:

```
[ -d "$d" ] && dirs[i++]="${d%/}"
```

instead of saying:

```
dirs[i++]="${d%/}"
```

---

Quoting `help test`:

```
  -d FILE        True if file is a directory.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in *
do
  [ -d ${i} ] && echo $i
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
for d in /var/www/*
```

...do it like this (notice the trailing `/`):

```
for d in /var/www/*/
```

It will only match directories.